# Forking children in C and re-forking when they die

Tags: c++, c, multiprocessing, ipc, daemon

I have some code that forks a number of child "workers".    Child labor :(

This works pretty good til a child dies due to some unpredictable error and the system throughput decreases.

What's a good pattern for monitoring for the children crashing,  then re-forking them with the same params I fired them up with?     I haven't written this type of code before and it looks like a little tricky.

Comment: which part is tricky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Unix-like system, you can use `wait` or `waitpid` in the parent to monitor subprocesses synchronously. Alternatively, you can use `SIGCHLD` to monitor them asynchronously, and call `wait` or `waitpid` in the signal handler. You will get notified whenever a subprocesses terminates(including crashing).

To re-fork a child with the same parameters when it crashes, you would have to record the parameters for each child.